# Как сделать ЧПУ в Wordspress?

Tags: cms, wordpress

Появился вопрос, как сделать ЧПУ в wordpress, хочу чтобы у конечных (детальных страниц, постов) было чпу такого вида: Сайт->категория1->подкатегория2->конечный пост

Answer (score 1):

День добрый.

Для создания новой структуры ссылок Вам нужно воспользоваться функцией [add_permastruct](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_permastruct).

После того как вы добавите новую структуру ссылок необходимо, в админке WP Настройки->Постоянные ссылки нажать кнопку сохранить. Или в коде Вашего приложения вызвать следующую конструкцию

```
//Ensure the $wp_rewrite global is loaded
global $wp_rewrite;
//Call flush_rules() as a method of the $wp_rewrite object
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( false );
```

!Нужно вызвать только один раз что бы добавить новую структуру ссылок, после того как все заработает нужно удалить выше указанную конструкцию она очень тормозит загрузку приложения.